# three.js unexpected resizing on mobile devices

Tags: performance, mobile, three.js

I am getting a strange issue with scaling scene in three.js only on mobile devices.

Everything is alright when I watch it on desktop, but on mobile it always scaling and blinking...

Here is link to codepen: https://codepen.io/elliepooh/pen/evXgdE

And here is my init function:

```
function init() {
 scene = new THREE.Scene();
 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
 camera.lookAt(scene.position);
 camera.position.set(30, 15, 15);

 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
 renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
 renderer.setSize(width, height);
 renderer.setClearColor(0xF2A9B4);
 renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
 renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

 controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

 raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
 mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

 addLights();
 drawChameleon();
 drawBranch();
 drawFly();

 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

 document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
 document.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove);
 window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);
```

}

Maybe I missed something?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "scaling and blinking." I ran your example on my phone, and it seemed fine, though my phone handles WebGL fairly well.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. I encountered this "blinking" error before when displaying a three.js scene on mobile. Are you testing this on iOS? If so, when you scroll down on ios, the browser's nav bar shrinks. Your code has `renderer.setSize(width, height)`, and will resize the entire canvas because of your event listener. When your canvas resizes, weird things happen because it's both trying to animate and resize...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem by appending domElement to existing div#world and adding this to my css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#world {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Great thanks to @AlexFallenstedt. Once I knew the reason was in iOS, not in my code, it made me relax and resolve the problem.

Comment: Never though of using css to fix this issue. I will totally reference this in my next project.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you mean. I encountered this "blinking" bug before when displaying a three.js scene on mobile. Are you testing this on iOS? If so, when you scroll down on ios, the browser's nav bar shrinks. Your code has `renderer.setSize(width, height)`, and will resize the entire canvas because of your event listener. When your canvas resizes, weird things happen because it's both trying to animate and resize...

How I got around it was by adding a function in `render()`

```
function resizeCanvas() {
  if (canvas.width != canvas.clientWidth ||
     canvas.height != canvas.clientHeight) {
    canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
}
```

It asks if the canvas' width and height is looks like the [client's width and height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth). If it doesn't, it kind of forces the canvas to be that width and height.

You can see it in action here:

https://github.com/Fallenstedt/Fallenstedt.github.io/blob/master/_js/index.js#L128-L135

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It really helped :)

Comment: @elliepooh. Glad it helped. :)